# Draw things after board is drawn with paint (JPanel) (java)

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, paint

I am trying to make a very simple Tic Tac Toe game in Java. However, I cannot figure out how to draw something after I've drawn the board. Here's my structure of my game.

```
public class ThreeInARowMain extends JPanel {

    public static final int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = 640;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("1.", 0,20);
        g.drawString("2.", 210,20);
        g.drawString("3.", 410,20);
        g.drawString("4.", 0,220);
        g.drawString("5.", 210,220);
        g.drawString("6.", 410,220);
        g.drawString("7.", 0,420);
        g.drawString("8.", 210,420);
        g.drawString("9.", 410,420);
        //Horizontal Lines
        g.drawLine(0, 200, WIDTH, 200);
        g.drawLine(0, 400, WIDTH, 400);
        //Vertical Lines
        g.drawLine(200, 0, 200, HEIGHT);
        g.drawLine(400, 0, 400, HEIGHT);

    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
    boolean firstorsecond = true;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ThreeInARowMain());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        boolean someonewins = false;
        int firstplayerpos, secondplayerpos;
        int [] [] board = new int [3] [3];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!someonewins){
        System.out.println("P1, enter the number of the square you'd like to mark.");
        firstplayerpos = in.nextInt();
        DrawXorO(firstplayerpos,firstorsecond);


        System.out.println("P2, enter the number of the square you'd like to mark.");
        secondplayerpos = in.nextInt();
        DrawXorO(secondplayerpos,!firstorsecond);

        }
    }

    public static void DrawXorO (int position, boolean firstorsecond) {

    }

}
```

I know this is a badly designed game at the moment; I will correct that later. However, what I want with DrawXorO is to draw an X or and O in the position that the player has typed in. How do I add graphics after using the method paint? Thanks!

Comment: Start by reading [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).  Don't override `paint`, instead of override `paintComponent` and make sure you call `super.paintComponent`

Answer (score 4):

- Don't mix console input (`Scanner`) with UI.  UI's are event driven, that is, something happens, you respond to it.
- Have a read of [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).  Don't override `paint`, instead of override `paintComponent` and make sure you call `super.paintComponent`
- And you might as well read through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)and [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for some ideas in how a UI works and how to respond to user interation

Comment: But so I cannot mix Scanner with UI's? So constructing the game the way I'd like to simply does not work? What I'd like to do is to let the user enters the position they'd like to mark in the console.

Comment: You can use buttons, mouse clicks, text fields or sort of things

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

[image: Tic Tac Toe GUI]

Here's one way to draw the tic tac toe diagram on the left of the GUI.  I have a model class that keeps the board position in a 2 dimensional int array, and a mouse controller class that let's me know where the person clicked on the tic tac toe diagram.

```
package com.ggl.tictactoe.view;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.tictactoe.controller.MouseMoveController;
import com.ggl.tictactoe.model.GameStatus;
import com.ggl.tictactoe.model.TicTacToeModel;

public class TicTacToePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9150412950439480699L;

    private MouseMoveController controller;

    private TicTacToeModel model;

    public TicTacToePanel(TicTacToeFrame frame, TicTacToeModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.controller = new MouseMoveController(frame, model);
        this.addMouseListener(controller);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360, 360));
    }

    public void setComputerMove() {
        if (!model.isPlayerGoesFirst()) {
            controller.setComputerMove();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        int[][] board = model.getBoard();
        int width = getWidth() / board.length;
        int height = getHeight() / board[0].length;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(7F);
        g2d.setStroke(stroke);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        x += width;
        for (int i = 0; i < (board.length - 1); i++) {
            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, getHeight());
            x += width;
        }

        x = 0;
        y += width;
        for (int i = 0; i < (board.length - 1); i++) {
            g2d.drawLine(x, y, getWidth(), y);
            y += width;
        }

        float fontSize = (float) height * 72F / 96F;
        Font largeFont = getFont().deriveFont(fontSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            x = width * i;
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                y = height * j;
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
                if (board[i][j] == 1) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    centerString(g2d, r, "X", largeFont);
                } else if (board[i][j] == -1) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    centerString(g2d, r, "O", largeFont);
                }
            }
        }

        if (model.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.TIE_GAME) {
            BufferedImage image = GameOverImage.createImage(getWidth(),
                    getHeight(), "Tie Game");
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        } else if (model.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.COMPUTER_WINS) {
            BufferedImage image = GameOverImage.createImage(getWidth(),
                    getHeight(), "Computer Wins");
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        } else if (model.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.PLAYER_WINS) {
            BufferedImage image = GameOverImage.createImage(getWidth(),
                    getHeight(), "Player Wins");
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method centers a <code>String</code> in a bounding
     * <code>Rectangle</code>.
     * 
     * @param g2d
     *            - The <code>Graphics2D</code> instance.
     * @param r
     *            - The bounding <code>Rectangle</code>.
     * @param s
     *            - The <code>String</code> to center in the bounding rectangle.
     * @param font
     *            - The display font of the <code>String</code>
     * 
     * @see java.awt.Graphics
     * @see java.awt.Rectangle
     * @see java.lang.String
     */
    private void centerString(Graphics2D g2d, Rectangle r, String s, Font font) {
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

        Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
        int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
        int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
        int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
        int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

        int a = (r.width / 2) - (rWidth / 2) - rX;
        int b = (r.height / 2) - (rHeight / 2) - rY;

        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.drawString(s, r.x + a, r.y + b);
    }

}
```

And here's the mouse controller code.

```
package com.ggl.tictactoe.controller;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import com.ggl.tictactoe.model.GameStatus;
import com.ggl.tictactoe.model.TicTacToeModel;
import com.ggl.tictactoe.view.TicTacToeFrame;

public class MouseMoveController extends MouseAdapter {

    private ComputerMoveRunnable controller;

    private TicTacToeFrame frame;

    private TicTacToeModel model;

    public MouseMoveController(TicTacToeFrame frame, TicTacToeModel model) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
        this.controller = new ComputerMoveRunnable(frame, model);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        if ((model.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.ACTIVE_GAME)
                && (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)) {
            int width = frame.getTicTacToePanel().getWidth();
            int height = frame.getTicTacToePanel().getHeight();
            int positionWidth = TicTacToeModel.getPositionWidth();

            Point p = event.getPoint();

            int x = getPosition(p.x, width, positionWidth);
            int y = getPosition(p.y, height, positionWidth);

            int[][] board = model.getBoard();
            if (board[x][y] == 0) {
                model.setPlayerMove(x, y);
                setComputerMove();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setComputerMove() {
        controller.run();
        frame.repaintTicTacToePanel();
    }

    private int getPosition(int location, int dimension, int squareWidth) {
        for (int i = 0; i < squareWidth; i++) {
            if (location < (dimension * (i + 1) / squareWidth)) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return squareWidth - 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. A bit above my level. However, very useful and good to look at. One question though; are import com.ggl.tictactoe.model.GameStatus;
import com.ggl.tictactoe.model.TicTacToeModel;
import com.ggl.tictactoe.view.TicTacToeFrame;

Comment: Are those written above external packages?

Comment: @Filip: I wrote the Tic Tac Toe code using standard Swing classes.  I posted 2 of the 9 classes that I wrote for the game.  The com.ggl imports are my own Java packages.  I keep the model code, view code, and controller code in separate packages.

Comment: I just posted all of the Java code on [Github](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/tic-tac-toe).

Answer (score 1):

I would redesign your GUI to utilize 9 `JButtons`, 1 for each square.  You can then call JButton methods e.g. `JButton.setText("X")` to make a square display X which would be much simpler.  If you really want to override paintComponent, you can create variables to store what each square is currently displaying, update those variables and call repaint() when you need an update.

Comment: Thank you, I actually did that and made the game completely out of JButtons. It's not the best looking game, however, it does work. Thanks for the tip, gave me good training.

Comment: No problem, there is actually a lot of JButton methods like setting background image/color etc that you can play with to make your gui look better.